# jQuery nav menu doesn't update first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm trying to build a custom navigation menu with 3 options. Initially, only the active option is visible. Clicking on the active option shows the other options, and upon clicking on another one, it is prepended at the beginning of the menu and the other list items are once again hidden.

```
// html
<ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
</ul>

// css
li {
    display: block;
}
li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}

// js
$(function(){
    $('li:first-child').on('click', function(){
        $(this).siblings().toggle()
    });

    $('li').not(':first-child').on('click', function(){
        $(this).prependTo('ul')
        $(this).siblings().hide()
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H85Yj/

However, the only issue is that after it executes once, it won't run again. I'm guessing that the `li:first-child` still remains as the first option. Any way I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (undocumented, so far as I can see, in the API for `prependTo()`) problem you appear to be experiencing is that, once you move the `li` element from the HTML, the event-binding is not transferred *with* them; therefore clicking on the `li` no longer triggers an event. The easiest way around that is to bind the events to the parent `ul` element, and handle the events there (as the `click` events bubble up through the DOM and are acted upon by the ancestor).

Therefore, I'd suggest:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
    var self = $(this),
        siblings = self.siblings();
    if (siblings.filter(':visible').length) {
        self.prependTo(self.parent());
        siblings.hide();
    }
    else {
        siblings.toggle();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/H85Yj/1/).

Although, on reflection, the following seems more simple:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
    var _self = $(this);
    if (_self.is(':first-child')) {
        _self.siblings().toggle();
    }
    else {
        _self.prependTo(_self.parent()).siblings().hide();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/H85Yj/2/).

Note that I've adjusted the CSS a little, too (to use simple CSS rather than SCSS); setting the `display: none` as the default rule for the `li` elements, and `display: block` for the `li:first-child` element (as opposed to the needlessly-complex `:not(:first-child)` rule you used originally).

References:

- [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: That worked perfectly. I didn't know about the undocumented problem, thanks for bringing it to light.

Comment: To be honest, it surprised me when it occurred to me what must be happening; but I'd always thought that `prependTo()` (and `prepend()`) maintained the event-handlers until today. Live and learn, and I'm glad to have been of help! :)